# Python Poker Program that compares 2 hands and decides the best hand

Tags: python, oop

I have tried to put a multitude of things for the `__str__` and `__repr__` for my code but I cant seem to figure out what to put in those. Some help would be appreciated or if someone thinks my code should be different let me know:)

```
import random

class Card(object):
    card_values = {'ace' : 13, 'king' : 12, 'queen' : 11, 'jack' : 10,
                    '10' : 9, '9' : 8, '8' : 7, '7' : 6, '6' : 5,
                    '5' : 4, '4' : 3, '3' : 2, '2' : 1}
    card_suits = {'spades' : u'♤', 'diamonds' : u'♦', 'clubs': u'♧', 'hearts' : u'♥'}
    def __init__(self, suit, name):
        self.name = name
        self.value = self.card_values[name]
        if suit in self.card_suits.keys():
            self.suit = suit

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.value < other.value

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.value > other.value

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self.value == other.value) and (self.suit == other.suit)

    def __str__(self):
        

    def __repr__(self):
        

    def get_value(self):
        return self.value

    def get_suit(self):
        return self.suit

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    def same_suit(self, other):
        return self.suit == other.suit

class Hand(object):
    def __init__(self, card_list):
        assert len(card_list) == 5
        self.cards = sorted(card_list)

    def determine_strength(self):
        score = self.high_card()
        if self.royal_flush():
            print("royal_flush")
            score += 1000
            return score
        elif self.straight_flush():
            print("straight_flush")
            score += 900
            return score
        elif self.four_of_a_kind():
            print ("four_of_a_kind")
            score += 800
            return score
        elif self.full_house():
            print ("full_house")
            score += 700
            return score
        elif self.flush():
            print ("flush")
            score += 600
            return score
        elif self.straight():
            print ("straight")
            score += 500
            return score
        elif self.three_of_kind():
            print ("three_of_kind")
            score += 400
            return score
        elif self.two_pair():
            print ("two_pair")
            score += 300
            return score
        elif self.one_pair():
            print ("one_pair")
            score += 200
            return score
        print ("high card")
        return score

    def flush(self):
        suit = self.cards[0].get_suit()
        return all([card.get_suit() == suit for card in self.cards])

    def straight(self):
        start = self.cards[0].get_value()
        for card in self.cards[1:]:
            if card.get_value() == (start + 1):
                start = card.get_value()
            else:
                return False
        return True

    def straight_flush(self):
        return (self.straight() and self.flush())

    def royal_flush(self):
        return ((self.cards[0].get_name() == '10') and self.straight_flush())

    def _pair(self):
        count = 0
        names = [card.get_name() for card in self.cards]
        for i in range(len(names)):
            if (names[0:i] + names[i+1:]).count(names[i]) == 1:
                count += 1
        return count

    def one_pair(self):
        return self._pair() == 2

    def two_pair(self):
        if self.three_of_kind():
            return False
        return self._pair() == 4

    def _of_a_kind(self):
        count = {}
        names = [card.get_name() for card in self.cards]
        for name in names:
            if name not in count:
                count[name] = 1
            else:
                count[name] += 1
        return max(count.values())

    def three_of_kind(self):
        return self._of_a_kind() == 3

    def four_of_a_kind(self):
        return self._of_a_kind() == 4

    def full_house(self):
        return (self.one_pair() and self.three_of_kind())

    def high_card(self):
        return max([card.get_value() for card in self.cards])

    def __str__(self):
        

    def __repr__(self):
```

Comment: It depends on how you want to represent a card. I would try `return f"{self.name} {self.value} {self.suit}"` first.

Comment: would that be for my repr as well ?

Comment: That's for `__repr__`. If you omit `__str__` Python will use `__repr__` for that as well.

Comment: File "C:\Users\nbrin\Desktop\pokerLab\test.py", line 177, in <module>
    run_hand(rf)
  File "C:\Users\nbrin\Desktop\pokerLab\test.py", line 151, in run_hand
    print (H)
  File "C:\Users\nbrin\Desktop\pokerLab\test.py", line 147, in __repr__
    f"{self.name} {self.value} {self.suit}"
AttributeError: 'Hand' object has no attribute 'name'

Comment: that is the error message I am getting

Comment: My example was for the `Card` class. You should modify it for `Hand`.

Comment: what would be soemthing for the hand class. Sorry I dont get the rprs at all

Comment: I _don't know_. A sample output of what you want to see would be helpful. `__repr__` is not a magical function, it should just return a string that could uniquely describe the class instance.